# How can I dereference an emacs lisp variable?

Tags: pointers, emacs, lisp, elisp

```
  (defun save-interface-file ()
      (interactive)
      (let* ((xml (buffer-string))
             (root (with-temp-buffer (insert xml) (xml-parse-region (point-min) (point-max))))
             (request (car root))
             (nodename (xml-node-name request))
             (CustomerAgencyDataLoad "CALI")
             )
             (message "%s.CRM66898.VZCRMCAR%s.%s" (number-to-string (random 100000000)) (derefernce nodename) (number-to-string (random 100000)) )

        )
      )
```

I have the above function defined in my emacs.init file
I open a buffer containing xml and type

```
M-x save-interface-file
```

What happens is the variable node name will contain the value "CustomerAgencyDataLoad". In the message I want to dereference this from nodename and print "CALI". If I print nodename I get "CustomerAgencyDataLoad". I know this sort of dereferencing works in perl using $$var however how do I achieve this in emacs LISP?

Answer (score 2):

While you can deference a variable using `(symbol-value (intern "my-string"))` (except if your code is compiled using lexical binding), in this case I'd suggest using an alist (short for "association list") instead:

```
(let ((shorter-names '((CustomerAgencyDataLoad . "CALI")
                       (SomethingElse . "FOO")))
      (node-name 'CustomerAgencyDataLoad))
  (cdr (assq node-name shorter-names)))
```

`assq` searches through `shorter-names` for an entry that matches the value of `node-name`.  With `cdr`, we get the second half of the entry, which is `"CALI"` in this case.